# Discovering or predicting correct data type for object properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following json extracted from excel:

```
  {
    "Name": "Joe",
    "Address": "Some address",
    "Email": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "Age": "20",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "DateBirth": "1989/12/08",
    "Salary": "2,500.00",
    "Married":"False"
  }
```

Is there a way in javascript to detect what kind of data type must be assigned for each properties? ex.

Name : **String**

Address : **String**

Email : **String**

Age : **Integer**

Gender : **String**

DataBirth: **Date**

Salary: **Decimal / Float**

Married: **Boolean**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest to what you want i can get, it does not differenciate integer and decimal/float.

To implement this you need to loop over all your keys-value pairs and it will return the value in the correct type.

```js
let a = "true"
let b = "false"
let c = "5"
let d = "1,505.5"
let e = "hello world"
let f = "1989/12/08"

const returntype = (x) => {
  if(!isNaN(x)){
    return parseFloat(x) //returns the number
  }
  if(x === 'true'){
    return true
  } 
  if(x === 'false') {
    return false
  }
  if(!isNaN(Date.parse(x))){
    return Date.parse(x)
  }
  return x
}

console.log(returntype(a))
console.log(returntype(b))
console.log(returntype(c))
console.log(returntype(d))
console.log(returntype(e))
console.log(returntype(f))
```

The big problem here is the fact that you have a `,` in your float, js will handel it as a string.

you could add something like this

```js
x.replace(",", "")
```

To remove the comma, but you need to be sure you do not need them in an other string.